# Share EFS Block among Several Linux and Windows Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, samba, amazon-efs

I need a place where my Linux instances (Around 5) and a Single Windows instance can read/write from/to.
I thought of using an EFS block and it works well for Linux instances. I can mount it on more than one Linux instance and they can all work well together.
But I need to share the same EFS block to a Windows Instance and as per the official AWS documentation, EFS Blocks are not supported on Windows.

So, is it possible that I mount my EFS Block on a directory on Linux Instances and then Share that directory with my Windows instance via Samba?

If not then what are my alternatives?

Comment: "Not supported" doesn't necessarily mean "does not work."  Accessing EFS from outside AWS is also "not supported," but [it can be done](http://serverfault.com/a/799213/153161).  Assuming you have the ability to mount an NFS4 volume on a Windows machine (do you?), have you tried it?

Comment: I took the "Not Supported" clause too seriously. Will try and update it soon. Thanks!

Comment: http://goadingtheitgeek.blogspot.in/2015/08/fail-aws-efs-preview-on-aws-ec2-windows.html

Comment: That's interesting, but possibly outdated, since EFS claims to be NFS 4.1,  not 4 as this blog post indicates.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a necro-thread, but Windows Server includes a native NFS client which can be enabled as a Feature.

There are a couple of registry values which can set the default UID/GID for files on the share.